# FloatingActionButton strange press behavior

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-xml, floating-action-button

I have no idea what suddenly caused this, as I don't think I've changed any code (maybe this is an Android Studio 2.0 bug?).

But now when I press a FloatingActionButton, it stays pressed and doesn't do anything when I first click it. If I start clicking it again, it seems to work (but still looks pressed).

In my OnCreate method:

```
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    assert fab != null;

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           //does stuff here, behavior is the same even if I remove this code
        }
    });
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
            android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why you have `assert fab != null;`?

Comment: Just to get rid of a warning Android Studio was giving me; probably not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` from your FAB .

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
    />
```

Comment: That fixed it! I wonder why I had added that in the first place, or why only now it decided to start acting funny.